# Joining 2 result sets to replace values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, join

I have 2 SQL result datasets that I need merged into one to look like:

```
Final Merged Table
-------------
320 Sydney
321 Brisbane
322 Melbourne
```

The SQL to achieve this is a little more complicated since every data column is saved in the DB as a separate record against the User ID (due to Wordpress and the way it stores 'meta_value' data)

First result set:

```
User Table (A)
-------------
320 119 
321 120 
322 121
```

Achieved with:

```
SELECT wp_frm_items.id, meta_value AS city  FROM `wp_frm_items` 

INNER JOIN `wp_frm_item_metas` on wp_frm_item_metas.item_id = wp_frm_items.id 

WHERE `form_id` = 9 AND  field_id = 219
```

Second result set:

```
Location Table (B)
-------------
119 Sydney
120 Brisbane
121 Melbourne
```

Achieved with:

```
SELECT wp_frm_items.id, meta_value FROM `wp_frm_items` 

INNER JOIN `wp_frm_item_metas` on wp_frm_item_metas.item_id = wp_frm_items.id 

WHERE `form_id` = 10
```

MySQL keeps telling me I have an error in my final join code at line 7 "INNER JOIN":
(the above 2 SQL statements work fine)

```
SELECT * 

FROM (SELECT wp_frm_items.id, meta_value AS city  FROM `wp_frm_items` 
INNER JOIN `wp_frm_item_metas` on wp_frm_item_metas.item_id = wp_frm_items.id 
WHERE `form_id` = 9 AND  field_id = 219 ) AS A 

INNER JOIN

SELECT * 

FROM (SELECT wp_frm_items.id, meta_value FROM `wp_frm_items` 
INNER JOIN `wp_frm_item_metas` on wp_frm_item_metas.item_id = wp_frm_items.id 
WHERE `form_id` = 10) AS B 

ON A.city = B.id
```

Can anyone shed some light for me on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. The short answer is you don't need the `SELECT * FROM` in the join clause, just specify the (derived) table itself:

```
SELECT * 

FROM (SELECT wp_frm_items.id, meta_value AS city  FROM `wp_frm_items` 
INNER JOIN `wp_frm_item_metas` on wp_frm_item_metas.item_id = wp_frm_items.id 
WHERE `form_id` = 9 AND  field_id = 219 ) AS A 

INNER JOIN
    (SELECT wp_frm_items.id, meta_value FROM `wp_frm_items` 
    INNER JOIN `wp_frm_item_metas` on wp_frm_item_metas.item_id = wp_frm_items.id 
    WHERE `form_id` = 10) AS B 

ON A.city = B.id
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! That was it! Wow talk about going nuts there. You saved my sanity. I'll accept this as the answer. Thanks again.